# SQL look up abbreviation value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

So i have declared a table:

```
  DECLARE @VTable TABLE (ColtoAdj VARCHAR(50),HeadlineDescription 
  VARCHAR(50),HeadlineDescriptionGroup VARCHAR(50));

  INSERT INTO @VTable VALUES ('Neopla','Neoplasia','Cancer');
  INSERT INTO @VTable VALUES ('Metasta','Metastases','Cancer');
  INSERT INTO @VTable VALUES ('CES','CES','Cauda Equina');
  INSERT INTO @VTable VALUES ('CES-I','CES-I','Cauda Equina');
```

which is then used in an Outter apply on the main table to find the headlinedescription and headlinedescriptiongroup.

```
  OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1
  vt.ColtoAdj,
  Vt.HeadlineDescription,
  Vt.HeadlineDescriptionGroup
  FROM @VTable AS vt
  WHERE cmd.Headline LIKE ('%' + vt.ColtoAdj + '%')
```

Which for most of my data it works fine as alot of the vt.ColtoAdj lookup words are unique such as have a hyphon etc. so are only pulled. The problem is the CES value. This could be anywhere in a 255 character headline. So its currently picking up things like "BraCES" and adding it incorrectly. I tried to insert 2 values for it '*CES' or 'CES*' to just get the abbreviation but this still grabs words ending in it or starting. Is there anyway for this value in the table i can get it to find just the 3 letters by themselves, but also search for full words for the other ones?

It may be a case of no, simply because its a like function and with a word lookup you cant always guarantee 100% accuracy, but thought i would check.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for word boundaries and words are bounded by a space, you can use:

```
WHERE ' ' + cmd.Headline + ' ' LIKE '% ' + vt.ColtoAdj + ' %'
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you. I believe this has done the trick. Simple but couldnt think of it.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of a per-case solution:

```
WHERE 
(
    (cmd.Headline LIKE ('%' + vt.ColtoAdj + '%') and vt.ColtoAdj<>'CES')
    OR
    (cmd.Headline='CES' and vt.ColtoAdj='CES')
)
```